# Salesforce composite capable

Tags: salesforce, mulesoft

Can anyone please help me? Is Salesforce composite capable of a rollback strategy? In case I have 3 records being updated to a Salesforce object and the last records got failed,
will it be able to revert/roll back and reprocess again the same record and avoid duplicating the records?

Comment: Are you asking for a specific Mule connector? please indicate version of Mule and the connector. Provide as much detail as possible of the context and use case increases the possibilities of receiving an answer. It is strongly recommended to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking.

Comment: Salesforce composite connector has the feature of roll back but which version of connector you are talking about? and which mue version you are using?